# What are kinetic and potential terms in binding energy and provided they are of the same order of magnitude, why can't we measure nuclear force?

Tags: nuclear-physics, binding-energy

In my  introductory nuclear physics course notes there is an statement I don't understand:

> "The intensity of nuclear force cannot be measured directly from the binding energy observed in nuclei because it contains the kinetic energy term (positive) which is of the same order of magnitude of the potential energy term."

I don't know what they mean with the "kinetic energy term" and the "potential energy term". In the expression for the binding energy:
$$ E_{\rm {B}}=-a_{\rm {V}}A+a_{\rm {S}}A^{2/3}+a_{\rm {C}}{\frac {Z(Z-1)}{A^{1/3}}}+a_{\rm {A}}{\frac {(N-Z)^{2}}{A}}+\delta (N,Z).$$
We have: Volume energy, Surface energy , Coulomb energy, Asymmetry energy and Pairing energy.

Can someone please explain what they mean with kinetic energy and potential energy,why they have the same order of magnitude and why that is a problem when measuring the nuclear force?

Answer (score 0):

In quantum mechanics if two (or more) objects are in a bound state they have both potential and kinetic energy. In non-relativistic mechanics [correctie: en 1/r potentialen] quite generally, the [virial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem#In_quantum_mechanics) holds. It states that in a stationary state the time averaged potential energy equals minus two times the time averaged kinetic energy. In relativistic mechanics the ratio is different. Therefore knowledge of only the binding energy is insufficient to determine the potential energy unless you know the ratio to the kinetic energy.

Comment: Do some of the terms of the binding energy correspond to potential energy while others to the kinetic energy, if yes, which ones?. Or is it another way to justify and subdivide the binding energy?

Comment: Non-relativistic kinetic energy is the expectation value of $P^2/2m$ but I don't know what your hamiltonian looks like.

Comment: From your answer should I assume that relativistic mechanics is to be used for the kinetic and potential energy of the nucleous? If so, you said the ratio of kinetic and potential energy is different, but you didn't said the value. Is it unknown? And is that why nuclear force can't be measured?

Comment: I am confused. I haven't been introduced any hamiltonian in nuclear physics. Is the hamiltonian the same as the binding energy without considering the rest energies of the nucleons?

Comment: Your stated ratio only holds for $1/r$ potentials. For $1/r^n$ potentials, the $-2$ becomes $-2/n$. (The virial theorem can always be stated as a $-2$-ratio fact, but the denominator is no longer mean potential energy in general.) Since the strong potential isn't of the form $1/r^n$, the virial theorem would create the trouble you cite even if we had to worry about neither quantum nor relativistic effects.